# How can we add multiple checks in a middleware to perform certain check in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I recently started learning Laravel and I was developing a CRUD blog where the users are divided into 3 roles. The Owner, The Admin and The Author. So I wanted Owner to be the top most auth that can make or remove users from the post of "Admin". 
The second auth should be the Admin who can moderate, confirm or delete posts from the blog and can do almost everything an Owner can do but cannot ban or demote the Owner.

So i created a Users page where list of all registered users get displayed say: `localhost:8000/users`
Now I want only Owners and Admins to access this page and not the Authors. So to achieve this, I created a two functions in the User model just to check if user is an Owner (`isOwner()`) and if user is an admin (`isAdmin()`) and then made a middleware. Now in middleware, I want to add the rule that if user is Owner or Admin, let them access the users page, else return them back to home page and flash an error message.
The Code of my middleware is below

```
public function handle ($request, Closure $next) {
    if (!auth()->user()->isOwner() || !auth()->user()->isAdmin()) {
        session()->flash('error', 'You are not authenticated to perform this action');
        return redirect('home');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

But this is not acting as I want it. This is just now allowing anyone to access the users page. When I remove the OR (||) from the if statement, then it works fine but just checks for either Admin or Owner. How can I make it work for both? Am I doing something wrong? I tried many different ways but none is working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the condition:

```
public function handle ($request, Closure $next) {
    if (auth()->user()->isOwner() || auth()->user()->isAdmin()) {
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        session()->flash('error', 'You are not authenticated to perform this action');
        return redirect('home');        
    }
}
```

But we use policies and gates for the same like a blog user can delete there blog and admin can delete that blog, we can use middleware as well, if you want to do for specific module or tables then use polices and gates, With the help for polices you can manage on all the CRUD operation with different different conditions.

Comment: You don't really need the else there.

Comment: Yup, I know there is no need of else, but for make structured and clean code.